# setAdapter does not work

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

my setadapter does not work.

> Cannot resolve method
>   'setAdapter(android.widget.ArrayAdapter)'

This first segment is just my setup

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MainActivity MainActivity;

 TextView lappView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    lappView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lappView);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            changeLapp();

        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

I think the problem might be with me importing my arraylist from my other class.

```
void changeLapp() {
    MainActivity = new MainActivity();
    ArrayList<String> lappArrayGame = MainActivity.lappArray;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(GameActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MainActivity.lappArray);
    lappView.setAdapter(adapter);
    lappArrayGame.remove(0);
}
}
```

Comment: MainActivity = new MainActivity???

Comment: `MainActivity = new MainActivity();` is a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use `RecyclerView` instead of `TextView` type, for `lappView`.
2. After `lappArrayGame.remove(0);`, you need to call `notifyItemRemoved(0);` so that the UI will be updated accordingly.